# Benefit of cloud computing

Tags: cloud

I read that one of the benefits of cloud computing is "Shared Resources" .
"With cloud computing, this allows companies all to have access to the resources via cloud computing". But what is different between the time when companies make a web site and put all their resources on it and add a log in option for making it secure and the time when put their data in cloud ? Can any one explain it for me please?

Comment: Here is a good resource on cloud computing: http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/words-to-avoid.html#CloudComputing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure I got the question correctly. To me you have misunderstood the meaning of "shared resources". In the context of cloud computing, shared resource is usually a peace of

- hardware
- software
- infrastructure

Shared resources mean that same software or equipment can be used by many companies (but not at the same time). Given you have low demand, you can reduce your company's bill by consuming less cloud resources - you return them to the cloud. Once the demand is high, you can dynamically request more resources from the cloud.

Comment: but in google.doc we can access it at the same time. Is it different?

Comment: @SunyGirl, right is this what you meant under the **shared**? IMO, that feature is not connected to the term **cloud**. It just allows multiple users to work on the same document (one meaning of the word *shared*). But because it is used by millions of users, this functionality will be too hard to be implemented on 1 virtual machine (or server if you will). Therefore, there are thousands of VM (servers), taken from the cloud and returning to the cloud, depending on the absolute load (another meaning of the word shared). In this way google.docs is served to different companies.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean, what's the difference between having a web application with a companies data on it, like a school intranet website, and a system of storing data on a particular set of servers and allowing access to those servers from remote locations? In that case, I guess there is no difference, except the medium through which you access the data - one is just through a wb browser connecting to the data.

Comment: Yes, in a school website we access our data through web browser but in cloud computing how we access  our data?

Comment: If you use a service like mozy.com, they'll provide you with software, even apps on iPhones, etc., so you can always have access to your data as if it were stored locally. Much like an FTP client.

Answer (score 1):

one major thing with the cloud is that its hosted.  so you never have to worry about hardware.  as for data access you can do anything u could on your own server.  also the cloud can auto expand size and bandwidth limitlessly.

Comment: Yes you are right but I can put all my data on a web site and create user accounts for my users with out putting it on a cloud. My question is exactly what user2647 tells above.